# How to display/draw a screen lock pattern with numbers as inputs

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, html

How to display/draw a 9-dot screen lock pattern by feeding numbers as input USING PHONEGAP(HTML, JAVASCRIPT,JQUERY, CSS)...(Assuming and naming the dots from 1-9 respectively)..For example, if i provide the input  sequence as 1236987, then my output should be like this

```
[ 1  → 2  → 3
            ↓
  4    5    6
            ↓
  7  ← 8  ← 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is kind of what you are wanting... quick and dirty... used tables.. didn't do all of the arrow directions

http://jsfiddle.net/mattnull/YaCRe/2/